# Wrap multiple div elements on same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, wrapall

I would like to use jQuery to wrap sets of class elements in a `div` but can't find the solution.

HTML:

```html
<div class="view-content">

  <div class="first">content</div>
  <div class="first">content</div>
  <div class="second">content</div>
  <div class="third">content</div>
  <div class="third">content</div>

</div>
```

Desired Result:

```html
<div class="view-content">

  <div class="column">
    <div class="first">content</div>
    <div class="first">content</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="second">content</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="third">content</div>
    <div class="third">content</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/kQz4Z/8/

API: http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/

Added a break line so that you can see the difference here :) http://jsfiddle.net/kQz4Z/10/

**code**

```
$(function() {

    $('.first').wrapAll('<div class="column" />')

    $('.second').wrapAll('<div class="column" />')

    $('.third').wrapAll('<div class="column" />')




    alert($('.view-content').html());
});​
```

Comment: @h2ooooooo here you go http://jsfiddle.net/ZXb4Y/1/ :)) Nice one! set it as your answer if you want, cheers.

Comment: Guys, and how about [mine dynamical](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10896724/1249581)? :)

Comment: @VisioN Broooo how have you been :P okies +1 to you as well man

Answer (score 3):

Use wrapAll() method

```
$(function(){
    var classes = ['.first', '.second', '.third'];

    for (i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        $(classes[i]).wrapAll('<div class="column">');
    }​

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g9G85/

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Or here is the very short dynamical solution:

```
​$(".view-content > div").each(function() {
    $(".view-content > ." + this.className).wrapAll("<div class='column' />");
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/CqzWy/

Comment: It should be noted that this method in its current form MUST employ the child combinator selector (>) as shown. Failure to do so will result in a wrapping div for each item that matches a certain className. (For example, in this case, divs with class "third" would be wrapped in TWO divs with class "column").

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.wrap()` to wrap something in a `div` but if your content is not ordered it will become a mess, here's an example:

Input

```
<div class="view-content">
    <div class="first">content</div>
    <div class="second">content</div>
    <div class="first">content</div>
</div>
```

Output

```
<div class="view-content">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="first">content</div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="second">content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="first">content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try whit this:

```
var arr = $(".view-content div").map(function() { return $(this).attr('class'); }).get();
var results = $.unique(arr);
var i;

for(i = 0; i < results.length; i++){

    $('.out').append('<div class="columns"></div>');
    $('.'+results[i]).clone().appendTo('.columns:last');
}

alert($('.out').html());
```

Here an example:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/V6Sq9/)