# Need to wrap specified content

Tags: jquery, html

This is my code, this message coming from dynamicaly

```
<div class="left">6 item(s) - Page 1 of 3 </div>
```

Need to change

```
<div class="left"> <span>6</span> item(s) - Page <span>1</span> of <span>3</span> </div>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: see this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896332/jquery-wrap-multiple-div-elements-on-same-class/10897813#10897813)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var div = $('.left');
div.html(div.html().replace(/(\d+)/g, '<span>$1</span>'));
```

Comment: When will I learn regex :(. Anyways +1 for such a nice and precise solution.

Answer (score 1):

Split the text by "Space". You will get the array of items. Take the index, I thought It will always same and add your "span" on that.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.
I simply check if a word is a number. If yes, I wrap it inside a `span`

```
var left = $('.left');
var html = left.html().split(' ');
for(var i=0,len=html.length;i<len;i++){ 
    if(!isNaN(html[i]) && html[i]!=''){
        html[i] = '<span>' + html[i] + '</span>';
    }
}
left.html(html.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the implicit looping that comes natively in jQuery to reset the html of each matched element.

```
​$(".left").html(function(i,v){
    return v.replace( /(\d+)/g, "<span>$1</span>" );
});​​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/gEYEE/