# Wrap group of elements in multiple HTML elements using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to add HTML into a page but I have no direct control over the HTML itself so am trying to use JQuery.

This is the existing, generated HTML (simplified):

```
<div class="curriculum>Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
<div class="testimonial">Content</div>
<div class="testimonial">Content</div>
<div class="testimonial">Content</div>
<div class="curriculum>Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
```

Wherever the `.testimonials` appear, I need to group them all and wrap in HTML so the output looks like:

```
<div class="curriculum>Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <h2>Testimonials</h2>
      <div>

        <div class="testimonial">Content</div>
        <div class="testimonial">Content</div>
        <div class="testimonial">Content</div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>       

<div class="testimonial">Content</div>
<div class="curriculum>Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
```

*Note that I need to add the 3 containing `<div>` tags and the `<h2>` (and the relevant closing tags) for styling reasons.*

I was hoping to simply grab the first and last testimonials using `.first().before` and `.last().after` to add the HTML but JQuery adds the closing tags. I've also tried using JQuery's various `.wrapAll`, `.before`, `.append` but have had no luck for reasons I don't understand!

Other solutions on stackoverflow all seem to deal with wrapping the group of elements in a single `<div>` but I have trouble when trying to add the other `<div>`s and the `<h2>`

Does anybody have any advice how this could be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery wrap multiple div elements on same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896332/jquery-wrap-multiple-div-elements-on-same-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably easier if you don’t try to use wrapping methods ...

I would simply create the HTML structure for your wrapper in one go,

```
var $wrapper = $('<div><div><h2>Testimonials</h2><div></div></div></div>');
```

and insert that before the first `.testimonial` element:

```
$wrapper.insertBefore('.testimonial:first');
```

And then simply grab all `.testimonial` elements and append them to the innermost div element of the new structure we just created ...

```
$wrapper.find('div div').append($('.testimonial'));
```

Check the resulting DOM in this example, it should be what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/rjh4ybxr/1/

Comment: Thanks, a nice simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

I defined an `id` to the `div` so it will be easily found later.

Hope this helps:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $( ".testimonial" ).wrapAll( "<div id='testimonial'></div>" );

    $( "<h2>Testimonial</h2>" ).insertBefore( "#testimonial" );

});
```

```css
body{
  background: gainsboro;
}
#testimonial{
  background:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
<div class="testimonial">Content</div>
<div class="testimonial">Content</div>
<div class="testimonial">Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this for if there were multiple cases of testimonials that needed grouping.

```js
//find testimonials that are preceeded by a curriculum
$('.curriculum + .testimonial').each(function(){
  var $firstTestimonial = $(this);
  //get the first testimonial and all the immediately following testimonials
  var $group = $firstTestimonial.add($firstTestimonial.nextUntil(':not(.testimonial)'));
  //create a replacement with a id for the target of where the group should go
  var $replacement = $('<div><div><h2>Testimonials</h2><div id="tempTarget"></div></div></div>');
  
  //put the replacement where the first testimonial was
  $firstTestimonial.replaceWith($replacement);
  //put all the testimonials in the group in the replacement, and then get rid of the temporary id
  $replacement.find('#tempTarget').append($group).removeAttr('id');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
<div class="testimonial">Content</div>
<div class="testimonial">Content</div>
<div class="testimonial">Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
<div class="testimonial">Content</div>
<div class="testimonial">Content</div>
<div class="testimonial">Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
<div class="testimonial">Content</div>
<div class="testimonial">Content</div>
<div class="testimonial">Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
<div class="curriculum">Content</div>
```